# Why does running `strace echo "hello world" | grep write` show the full strace output?

Tags: linux, shell

Here is the full command I'm running. I'm not sure why its not filtering for only write syscalls.

```
❯ strace echo "hello world" | grep write
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "hello world"], [/* 48 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55f4ad456000
...
write(1, "hello world\n", 12)           = 12
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output of `strace` goes to the standard error, not standard output.

Use redirection to write to stdout:

```
strace echo "hello world" 2>&1 | grep write
```

Or, in more recent bash versions,

```
strace echo "hello world" |& grep write
```

Answer (score 1):

As user *choroba* pointed out, the output of `strace` goes to the standard error.
I just wanted to point out that you can **omit grepping** by filtering writes using the option `-e write`, although you will still get the exit message `"+++ exited with SSS +++"` which `grep` would filter out.

On the other hand, I've seen on the [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) of newer versions of `strace` that you can filter out the exit code message with `-e quiet=exit` or `--silence=exit`.

The result would be:

```sh
strace -e write,quiet=exit echo "hello world"
```